# How to Remove Overlap Using Window Function in Hive/Spark SQL

Tags: sql, hive, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a table with customer and product information.

```
customer_id promotion_id   product_id  Rank
1               555            222      1
1               555            223      1 
1               555            999      1
1               556            154      2
1               556            222      2
1               556            278      2 
1               557            432      3
1               557            434      3
1               557            435      3
```

Some of the promotions overlap in product information. For example promotion_id 555 and 556 can be used on product 222. I would like to remove  promotion_id 556 and rerank so that promotion 557 is ranked 2nd like so:

```
customer_id promotion_id   product_id  Rank
1               555            222      1
1               555            223      1 
1               555            999      1
1               557            432      2
1               557            434      2
1               557            435      2
```

I've been messing around using the row_number()/rank() function in SQL but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: What about product_id 278 part of promotion_id 556?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY promotion_id) AS new_rank
FROM (SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID 
                                  ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID, PROMOTION_ID) rn
      FROM tab) s
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but I'm afraid this did not work.

Comment: @DataTx Counterexample?

Comment: `Row_Number()` needs to be switched to `DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, PRODUCT_ID  ORDER BY PRODUCT_ID, PROMOTION_ID )`

Comment: but your suggestion was definitely the right direction for me.